# USB outlet wiring with three wire in and only spots for two

Tags: electrical

I want to install a usb outlet in place of a regular one. The old outlet has 3 black and three white wires. I believe one wire is power in and two are power out, one to another outlet in the same room and one to the outlet behind it in another room. The usb outlet only accepts two wires. I was going to pigtail two black together and put in on opening but am concerned if it makes a difference which two wires you pigtail together.

Comment: If you know one wire is power in and two are power out, then they can be connected together and add another short wire to them to outlet.

Comment: First check that the tab on the hot side is NOT broken on the outlet you have. But likely it isn't, with those wire colors, in most cases.

Comment: Pictures of how the old one was wired would be helpful to ensure we give you good guidance.

Answer (score 1):

First my obligatory editorial: In-wall USB outlets are a bad idea because they quickly become obsolete. Every new generation of phone uses a newer, faster, charging technology. They come with appropriate wall chargers, and within a year or so you can buy cheap duplicates for your kitchen, bedroom, car, etc. QC1, QC2, QC3, PD, etc etc .... chargers just keep getting better. An in-wall charger for your house is like a coal chute or a tie up for your horse, except it will be obsolete in 5 years not 100.

That said, to answer the question: If all the blacks are tied together now, and all the whites, you want to keep them that way, tied together inside the box along with a fourth wire to pigtail the new outlet.

I recommend you use 5-lever wagos for this purpose along with long, stranded, pigtails for the outlet that you can easily buy by the foot, because you **are** going to be performing maintenance on this thing and this approach makes it very very easy.

Note, if the junction box is metal one of the ground wires should be screwed down to it. That SHOULD be the one that supplies power, and you want to keep it that way.  Use a Wago (or whatever you want) to connect the loose end of that to all the other grounds.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I thought this was a great answer that covered it well. Yes, the in-receptacle chargers are also expensive, and in my experience, always "a few years behind the times"... to the point of near unusability.